# How to convert ruby array to support PostgreSQL array in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, postgresql

I have a following ruby array, need to convert array to support PostgresSQL array.

The array I have

```
ruby_array = ["9771", "9773", "9778", "9800", "9806"]
```

I need to convert this to following format

```
postgresSQL_array = {"9771", "9773", "9778", "9800", "9806"}
```

by using ruby

Comment: Can you explict the case you need it? It can be done on multiple ways which can be hard or easy depending on what you need

Comment: Are you using the `pg` gem and/or `ActiveRecord`?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "convert to postgres format"? What are you trying to **achieve**? Is your question about reading from / writing to the database? What task, specifically, are you trying to perform?

Comment: I don't think your question in its current form isn't really possible to answer -- because `{"9771", "9773", ...` is not valid ruby syntax, and you already know how to define the array in ruby: `["9771", "9773", ...`. I could suggest how to construct a **string** like `'{"9771", "9773", ... '` from the array, but that's probably not what you're actually looking for, and probably doesn't do anything to solve your underlying task.

Comment: Yes I knew that {"9771", "9773", "9778", "9800", "9806"}  is not ruby syntax. It's a PostgreSQL array format. I just simply need to convert ruby array format to PostgreSQL array format. Simply help me to construct a string like this -> '{"9771", "9773", "9778", "9800", "9806"} '

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the [PG gem](https://deveiate.org/code/pg/index.html), use [`PG::TextEncoder::Array`](https://deveiate.org/code/pg/PG/TextEncoder/Array.html) to convert a Ruby Array to a PostgreSQL Array.

```
connection.exec(
  "select $1::int[]",
  [PG::TextEncoder::Array.new.encode([1, 2, 3])]
)
```

If you're using Ruby on Rails, simply pass the Array as a parameter and it will convert for you.

```
Model.where(nums: [1,2,3])
```

---

Note that most things you can do with PostgreSQL Arrays are better done with [JSONB](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you simply need to create a string in that format, you can stringify the Ruby array, removing the first and last characters and inserting it between curly braces.

```
irb(main):001:0> ruby_array = ["9771", "9773", "9778", "9800", "9806"] 
=> ["9771", "9773", "9778", "9800", "9806"]
irb(main):002:0> postgresSQL_array = "{#{ruby_array.to_s[1...-1]}}"
=> "{\"9771\", \"9773\", \"9778\", \"9800\", \"9806\"}"
irb(main):003:0> puts postgresSQL_array
{"9771", "9773", "9778", "9800", "9806"}
=> nil
```